# How to read template expression in Java Xtend and what is it used for?

Tags: java, templates, xtend

I am trying to understand Xtend and was stuck at the 'template expression' part. This is the documentation of [Xtend](https://eclipse.org/xtend/documentation/203_xtend_expressions.html). Here I dont really understand what is the use of the 'Template expressions' and how to actually use/declare or read them.

Could somebody please be kind enough to give me a brief idea?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the documentation is fairly readable and detailed, you can find there everything about how to declare and use template expressions.

For me, the most important use case is to replace code fragments with lots of `StringBuilder.append()` calls with a single template expression.